# Java Graphics2D: How to Apply Perspective Transform to Graphics2D object?

Tags: java, transformation, graphics2d

Something I've been banging my head against for a while in Java is Perspective Transform.

I want to make an object in my game animate trapezoidaly. This means applying a different Perspective Transformation to it each frame.

The problem is that Graphics2D.transform() only accepts AffineTransformations for some reason. A PerspectiveTransform class does exist, as well as the ease of making a Double[3][3] matrix, but neither of those work.

Like...it would be easy if I could just set the projection matrix manually, but an AffineTransformation doesn't actually have variables for locations M20 and M21.

I've googled and searched on this site for DAYS and while a handful of people have brought it up, nobody has given an answer.

Comment: Maybe this is dumb question, but perspective transformation is 3D operation (If I [understand correctly](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dip/perspective_transformation.htm)) so wouldn't it require Z coordinate to work? Also trapezoid is flat shape, how is it related to perspective? Isn't [translate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#translate(double,double)) what you need?